# 3D vector graphics into PDF

Tags: pdf, 3d

I'm looking for **any** kind of technology that will let me draw dashed curves in 3D (see attachment) and export it into PDF with a guarantee that dashed lines are still paths in PDF file (not a collection of single little lines!).

[image: Dashed beziers in 3D]

I tried Processing, but see no option there to export it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In theory you can do this if you have the set of Beziers that describe each line and then set set the dash pattern for the line.  The dash pattern will be non-uniform and specified to cover the entire length of each path.

The problem I think you will run into is that line thickness cannot vary over the length of a single path, so you can't really get the effect of perspective in the change of line thickness.

How to do this without line thickness change - project the 3D path of each curve onto 2D, measure the projected dash and gap lengths and construct the corresponding PDF path.